# Qt Python: How to copy text to QTextEdit widget without formatting?

Tags: python, qt

when I'm copying text to textedit Qt Widget I want it to be copied as it does in normal text editor but it gets formatted like the source format and does not give all the text copied.

I just want the text to be copied and shown like normal text formatting just like windows text editor

I tried to mess with formatting commands but no solution yet

Answer (score 0):

Create simple derived class from `QTextEdit`.

And override `insertFromMimeData` function as shown below.

While overriding convert the text to plain text.

```
class QEnhancedTextEdit(QTextEdit):

    def insertFromMimeData(self, mimeData):
        #Ensure it is text.
        if (mimeData.hasText()):
            text = mimeData.text()
            self.insertPlainText(text)
        #In case not text.
        else:
            QTextEdit.insertFromMimeData(self, mimeData)
```

And now use this `QEnhancedTextEdit` to create text edit instead of `QTextEdit`

```
self.textEdit = QEnhancedTextEdit()
```

Comment: It's probably better to use `insertPlainText()` instead of `setPlainText()`. The latter will replace all existing text. It's also a good idea to add a `else` block with a `super()` call to restore default behaviour for non-text cases.

Comment: Yes . I agree with you.